# JavaCard: Overlay and restrictions for CLEAR_ON_DESELECT transients?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

In Java Card (I'm interested in Classic downto 2.1.1), transient (RAM) needed by an applet is  typically allocated on install by `makeTransientByteArray()`. That method accepts a parameter `CLEAR_ON_RESET` or `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT`. The later comes with warning that

> `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` transient objects can be accessed only when the applet which created the object is in the same context as the currently selected applet.
>
> The Java Card runtime environment will throw a SecurityException if a `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` transient object is accessed when the currently selected applet is not in the same context as the applet which created the object.

My reading is that `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` (but not `CLEAR_ON_RESET`) would allow the runtime to overlay the transients (allocated on install as stated above) between two applets, as long as they are not simultaneously selected, so that several applets allocating *m*<sub>j</sub> bytes would consume about max(*m*<sub>j</sub>) transient bytes, rather than sum(*m*<sub>j</sub>).

Update: I'm told something on the tune that on at least some runtime environments, the overlay occurs selectively for transients allocated from different packages. But I fail to find a reference, or a precise description of such rule/mechanism.

Question: Is this overlay mechanism sometime implemented in the runtime? If yes, when does it occurs? And are there cards with a runtime *not* implementing it? If yes, is there a way to tell other than by experiment, maybe from the version of Java Card advertised?

Other question: Precisely what does "context" mean in the quoted restriction? In particular, is a `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` transient usable by another instance of the applet, sharing it with the instance that allocated by the mechanism shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14257052/903600)? Note: I'm not interested in sharing the content of the transient, only in avoiding two allocations, to workaround a possible lack of overlay by the runtime.

Update: I asked the same question [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=10795498) and got an interesting answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct reason for Oracle to specify that `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` can be used to share memory between different applet instances, but it would be a very weird implementation if it didn't allow that to happen.

If it is specified anywhere, it is probably in the testing tools that Oracle makes available to companies implementing Java Card. Actually, the actual underlying memory model is not specified by Oracle at all, it's up to the implementation if they want to e.g. align data. Java Card byte code & CAP file format must be supported, but that's about it regarding the underlying implementation.

As for the context, from the VM specs:

> There is a one-to-one mapping between contexts and packages in which
>   applets are defined. An easy way to think of a context is as the
>   runtime equivalent of a package, since Java packages are compile-time
>   constructs and have no direct representation at runtime. As a
>   consequence, all applet instances from the same package will share the
>   same context.

Note that this does not mean that a `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` array won't be cleared if the applet is deselected in any way. This is just about access conditions. I will have to find out, but I guess if another applet in the same context uses the array, it will only be able to see zero'ed out bytes.

But this part about `CLEAR_ON_DESELECT` and context is just how I read the specs.

Comment: The reference to context is spot-on. Great! So correct me if I am wrong, but it seems that multiple instances of applets (from the same package) do NOT overlay the RAM used for their COD transcient allocated on install, unless they manage to share a single instance of that using a static, or some functionally equivalent sharing mechanism.

Comment: So it would seem. As said, the access is there so you could use the buffer to send data. Obviously retrieving data would not be an option as the data must be zeroed out. If the applets themselves can "overlay" data is not clear to me. Using statics is never a good idea on javacard...